Why did High Evolutionary say, "Toodle-oo"?
Adam Warlock fails to catch Rocket, which disappoints the High Evolutionary.
Consequently, the High Evolutionary warns the High Priestess:

High Evolutionary: Find 89P13 and return it to me, or I will destroy
your entire civilization, as is my right as your maker. Do you
understand? Do you understand?
High Priestess: Yes, sire.
High Evolutionary: Toodle-do.

I know “Toodle-oo” is a colloquial and somewhat old-fashioned way of saying “goodbye”
Why did High Evolutionary say, "Toodle-oo"?

There's nothing in the Director's Audio Commentary or the official Closed-Caption audio description that's especially helpful.

You're correct that it's colloquial. It's also rather disrespectful, as you might speak to a child or an inferior.
The High Evolutionary is contrasting his statement about possibly committing genocide against the Sovereign people with the casual way in which he dismisses her. She needs to take this very, very seriously, whereas he could destroy them with a mere wave of his hand.

+1 I agree, but I think the disrepect is contextual: 'Toodle-oo' is informal and affectionate between friends and family.
